# Ng2 lazy load module dependency in a lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, angular2-modules

I have an larger `editor.module` which is required by two lazy loaded modules  `a.module` and `b.module`. It like to move the editor away from app.module. Is it anyhow possible to define a third lazy loaded module `editor.module` as a lazy loaded dependency of `a.module` and `b.module`. Which ever is loaded first loads the editor module?

Comment: Nice question, did you find a way around it?

Comment: I have nearly the same question. In my case, Angular automatically made `editor.module` a non-lazy-loaded module. My problem currently is, that (at least in dev mode) the providers of `editor.module` are instantiated twice.